# Could not find gem 'canvas_connect (= 0.3.12 )' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, canvas-lms

When run bundle install getting this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4O3U.png

In Gemfile 

gem 'canvas_connect', '0.3.12'
    gem 'adobe_connect', '1.0.6', require: false

Comment: Can you share the source line  of gem file ?

Comment: gem 'canvas_connect', '0.3.12'
  gem 'adobe_connect', '1.0.6', require: false

Comment: Update the question with gem file code .

Comment: I said Whole gem file not only that portion

Comment: I guess the problem is with the version of the canvas_connect gem

Comment: Fetching this error when pulling code from one branch to another.

Comment: @ManishaOdedara remove the version specific from `canvas_connect` like `gem 'canvas_connect'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Canvas Connect](https://rubygems.org/gems/canvas_connect) Check this link for the available versions, the version mentioned in your Gemfile is wrong. Either update it with the version which you want to just remove it. Bundle will install the latest available .

[adobe_connect](https://rubygems.org/gems/adobe_connect) is a dependent gem and recheck the version mentioned with available versions.

Rubygems.org should be used as reference to compare and find gem versions

Answer (score 0):

Try installing these gems

```
gem 'canvas_connect', '~> 0.3.11'
```

and

```
gem 'adobe_connect', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.6', require: false
```

It seems like **0.3.11** is the latest version for **canvas_connect**.